# Increase legend follow time + dygraph

Tags: legend, dygraphs

On Dygraph LIVE data chart is there some configuration to increase the time to display legends on page while legend type is follow.

On the next refresh legends goes off - I want to display legends till the mouse is on the graph

OR if any one have idea how can call mouseMove(e) event on every update using updateOptions().

Comment: Ever figure this out? I want the legend to always be the last element in the dataframe unless the mouse is moved somewhere else on the graph but ran into the same as you. When the reactive variable triggers an update the legend goes away.